# MySQL: вставка радомного количества данных

Tags: php, база-данных, mysql

Добрый день, не так давно изучаю PHP столкнулся с такой проблемой. Есть таблица user_stat, в ней 34 колонки, дело в том что если при вставке данных в таблицу

```
 $inst = $db->prepare("insert into year_$year (user_name,type_of_day,month_row,day_1,day_2,day_3,day_4,day_5,day_6,day_7,day_8,day_9,
day_10,day_11,day_12,day_13,day_14,day_15,day_16,day_17,day_18,day_19,day_20,day_21,day_22,day_23,day_24,day_25,day_26,day_27,day_28,day_29,day_30,day_31)
values
(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

$inst->execute($chunk_post[$init]);
```

Если количество дней в месяце меньше 31 одного то массив `$shunk_post[$init]` содержит меньше данных (31-33) в место 34 и при вставке я получаю ошибку что количество вставляемых данных не соответствует количеству token-ов. Я решил проблему вот через такой костыль

```
if(count($chunk_post[$init])<34){
    while(count($chunk_post[$init]) < 34){
        array_push($chunk_post[$init],0);
    } 
}
```

Может есть способ по проще?!
Заранее благодарю

Comment: Появилась такая мысля тупо добавлять пустой массив типа dymmy = array[] с 34 значениями NULL и тут же его обновлять

Comment: Всем спасибо, обошелся 4 колонками  благодаря implode и explode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Список заполняемых полей для запроса генерировать на основе имеющихся данных (смотреть длину массива дней, или что там у вас).

Колонкам дней в базе задать значение по умолчанию NULL (и проверить что на них не стоит флаг "NOT NULL"), тогда при вставки, например, только одного дня из предполагаемых 31, остальные 30 ячеек по идее должны принять значение NULL.

Сомневаюсь что это самый правильный способ. Меня вообще терзают подозрения что в РСУБД, если по реляционному феньшую, вашу задачу надо решать как-то по-другому, без этих 31 колонок. Посмотрим что скажут знатоки РСУБД.